# Rails find returns nil even if there are records to be returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm working on a RoR project (RoR 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2p290) where I've run into some serious **strange problem with queries not finding things even if I know stuff should be found**.

For simplicity, say there is a `Car` model that has a `color` attribute. I have several records in the db, all with color black. Getting all records and displaying them in a view works fine and I see nothing strange at all.

```
@cars = Car.all
```

Here's from the console where I get the first car and checks if the color equals black:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :022 > Car.first.color == "Black"
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" LIMIT 1
 => true
```

This works fine as you can see. Now if I try to query with `find_by_color` it returns `nil`! That shouldn't be.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :021 > Car.find_by_color("Black")
  Car Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."color" = 'Black' LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Same goes for any type of query where I check the color, e.g.

```
find(:all, :conditions => { :color => "Black" })
```

I have tried everything I can come up with to try, but at the moment I have no clue what might cause something like this.

Any idea what this might be or where to start looking?

I'm thankful for any help in resolving this before I go insane ;)

**EDIT**

The colors are from a CSV file I imported through a file upload and parsing it into Car records. Could there be something with the encoding or something like that? Also I use SQLite in development in case that helps.

**UPDATE**

I tried another query that works!!

```
Car.where('color like ?', "Black")
```

This returns all the records. Very strange. What might be the difference between these queries?

Comment: Can you add a dump of a few records from your table? Look for leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Jeff Paquette, I have gone through all printing things out like puts "[" + c.color + "]", but there is nothing visible at least. Tell me if you'd like to see something special.

Comment: As @JeffPaquette says, your data may have formatting issues. Running a `find_by_...` query is stricter on matching and isn't as fuzzy as loading something through Rails's model relationships. If the SQL 'like' operator returns results but a direct query doesn't, there's likely a formatting or data storage issue. You may need to sanitize your database's records.

Comment: I think the `where()` should match exact as well, so in case there are spaces in there it shouldn't match.

Comment: @Piers, I have cleaned the database, only importing one CSV file to get some data. The problem remains. Is there some way I can check encoding or check that the data is correctly formatted in the database?

Comment: @murrekatt You can inspect the contents of your database directly by loading your SQLite `.db` file into an SQL database browser application and listing the contents of the Cars table. Try removing some data and manually re-entering what you expect to see, then searching again. Make sure you save your changes to the database before using Rails to query again.

Comment: Did you verify your data is in low ascii, or that you have the same character encoding set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was encoding and when I added

```
value.encode('utf-8')
```

to each field for the CSV file I imported I got proper values into the database.

The encoding problem seems to affect the queries differently.

Comment: It's generally a good practice to encode every string from outside your Rails app. Encoding problems cost me a lot of time already.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your color field has a strange non-printing character in the end, you must update field directly in database, cleaning up the extra characters.